# A convergence problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n$ converges.

I know the result that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n^p$ converge for $p \ge 1,$ and I try to use the root test to prove it.

Proof : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n \lt \infty \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\epsilon_n} \lt 1 \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\epsilon_n^p} \lt 1 \text{ (Since $x^p$ is continuous function)} \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n^p \lt \infty.$

End of Proof.

But I don't see why the proof using the root test fails in the case $0\lt p \lt 1$.

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n^p$ diverge when $0\lt p \lt 1,$ right?

I am so confused and sincerely want some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Sorry sir, I forgot to add the additional condition that $\epsilon_n$ is nonnegative. Thank you for your advice and I will try to prove directly using the definition next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong. It is not true that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \varepsilon_n < \infty \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\varepsilon_n} < 1.$$For instance, take $\varepsilon_n=\frac1{n^2}$. In this case, you have$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \varepsilon_n < \infty \text{ and } \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\varepsilon_n} = 1.$$The root test only asserts that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \varepsilon_n < \infty \Longleftarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\varepsilon_n} < 1.$$

---

Assuming that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\varepsilon_n\geqslant0$, you can solve your problem as follows: since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\varepsilon_n<+\infty$, $\varepsilon_n<1$ if $n$ is large enough. But ${\varepsilon_n}^p\leqslant\varepsilon_n$. Therefore, you can apply the comparison test.

Comment: Ahh, I see. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n \lt \infty \Leftarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\epsilon_n} \lt 1$, but the reverse side is wrong. Emmm, can you give me a proof that the series converges when $p \ge 1?$ I will be so grateful. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SamWong I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: Yes, it is clear now and I forget to add the condition that $\epsilon_n$ is non negative. Thank you José.